# How to replicate map, filter and reduce behaviors in C++ using STL?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, functional-programming

I suppose we can use std::transform to replicate the map behavior in C++ like this :

```
std::vector<int> in = { 1 , 2 , 3 ,4 }; 
std::vector<int> out(in.size()); 

std::transform(in.begin() , in.end() , out.begin() , [](const int & val)
{
    return val+1;
});
```

I guess a better way would be to use the back inserter.'

```
std::vector<int> out2;

std::transform(in.begin() , in.end() , std::back_inserter(out2) , [](const int & val){
      return val + 1;
});

// out will be { 2 , 3 ,4 ,5 }
```

Am I right ? How do I do the filter and reduce operations in C++ using STL ?

Comment: Define what "a better way" means to you. Keep in mind, that if you ask two C++ hackers what is a "better way" to do X, you'll get three different answers.

Comment: "Filter" probably corresponds to `std::copy_if` and/or `std::remove_if`. I'm not sure what "reduce" is supposed to do.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik haha. What do you find better ? Is there a 3rd way ? These are very interesting questions to me.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: reduce/fold is called `std::accumulate` in C++

Comment: `transform`, `copy_if`, `accumulate`.

Answer (score 58):

You can use `std::transform` to do mapping, and `std::copy_if` for filtering.

You have two options for reduce depending on your input and if you want to use a specific type of execution model. I've written some simple examples below to demonstrate common use cases. Note that there are multiple overloads for all these algorithms that you should use depending on your needs.

---

1. **`std::transform`**

Squaring a vector of integers in place:

```
std::vector<int> nums{1,2,3,4};
auto unary_op = [](int num) {return std::pow(num, 2);};
std::transform(nums.begin(), nums.end(), nums.begin(), unary_op);
// nums: 1, 4, 9, 16
```

2. **`std::copy_if`**

Filtering odd numbers only from a vector of integers:

```
std::vector<int> nums{1,2,3,4};
std::vector<int> odd_nums;
auto pred = [](int num) {return num & 1;};
std::copy_if(nums.begin(), nums.end(), std::back_inserter(odd_nums), pred);
// odd_nums: 1, 3
```

3. **`std::reduce`**

Sum of integers in the vector starting from 0 using parallel execution model. This is really useful if, for example, you are doing a reduce operation on a really big list. Reckon that the binary operator in this case ("+") is associate and commutative, otherwise the behavior would've been non-deterministic. This is really important. The reduce operation is out-of-order if the execution model is not sequential. Only available since C++17.

```
std::vector<int> nums{1,2,3,4};
auto binary_op = [](int num1, int num2){return num1 + num2;};
int result = std::reduce(
  std::execution::par, 
  nums.begin(), nums.end(), 
  0, binary_op
);
// result: 10
```

4. **`std::accumulate`**

Same as reduce except it doesn't support execution model and the reduce operation is done in-order.

```
std::vector<int> nums{1,2,3,4};
auto binary_op = [](int num1, int num2){return num1 + num2;};
int result = std::accumulate(nums.begin(), nums.end(), 0, binary_op);
// result: 10
```

Comment: remark: `std::pow` can produce wrong/unexpected results when used with integers

Answer (score 3):

Depends which container you use.

`std::back_inserter` will work only if the container has a `push_back` function.

For example `back_insterter` can't be used with `forward_list`.

In that case we need to have the memory allocated before we call `std::transform` on the same and first approach is better.

Answer (score 1):

I generalized the `transform` example from [happy_sisyphus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54300655/971090) into a function:

```
#include <algorithm>

// avoid calling this function 'map', it will clash with 'using std::map;'
template<typename I, typename F>
void apply_to_all(I& iterable, const F& functor)
{
    std::transform(iterable.begin(), iterable.end(), iterable.begin(), functor);
}
```

Example use:

```
std::vector<int> nums{1,2,3,4};
auto unary_op = [](int num) {return std::pow(num, 2);};

apply_to_all(nums, unary_op);
// nums: 1, 4, 9, 16
```