# Virtual dispatch in a loop

Tags: c++, optimization, vtable

I am wondering if there is a way to optimize case like following:

```
struct A{
   virtual process(int x) const = 0;
   virtual ~A() = default;
};

void useA(A const &a){
   for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
      a.process(i);
}
```

In case like this, if we promise somehow we wont change `a` vtable, the virtual lookup can be done only once, outside of the loop.

Is there a way to do something like this or result will be very negligible? Or probably there should be some other problem I do not see yet?

Comment: If I remember correctly, there is a command line flag on some compilers to tell it that you don't reconstruct another object on the this pointer

Comment: I think you can use this compilation option: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-fstrict-vtable-pointers

Comment: Doesn't branch(/jump) predictor can already do correct job?

Comment: If process takes "long" time, virtual call should be negligible. if process is short, is it really a problem? if yes, maybe change prototype to take range directly.

Comment: Whatever dispatch you're using, it's always going to be faster if you build your performance dependent dispatches on chunks of data instead of processing single data points individually.

Comment: Does process use any of `a`'s data members or functions?

Comment: we or compiler don't know this. May be, may be not. All we know the function is const, but this is not deliverate, I just made it like this when I tested assembly code.

Answer (score 3):

The whole reason the vtable gets checked every iteration in loop has to do with a ugly loophole in the language where you can destroy the object the virtual method is called on and recreate another object at the same memory. You can play some ping-pong that way and swap between classes every call of the virtual function.

I hope we all agree that such a code is unacceptable and we should be able to safely assume this doesn't happen in reasonable codebases. If so, you can tell the compiler about this with passing `-fstrict-vtable-pointers` on the command line of clang. I haven't found if GCC/MSVC supports the same flag.

Regarding the validity of the code I mentioned first, I found some C++ experts talk about this and still be confused, see the [twitter conversion](https://twitter.com/PiotrPadlewski/status/1302386543840112642?s=19)

Comment: A quick benchmark doesn't show any difference with or without the `-fstrict-vtable-pointers` flag: https://godbolt.org/z/YKfx9d

Comment: I should look into that in more detail, I need a bigger screen for that, that's for later

Comment: Looking at your code I don't even see a difference in assembly with this flag enable/disabled. You can see the difference here: https://godbolt.org/z/GqaPsr

Comment: Also if you first do a call on a, it does do something different. https://godbolt.org/z/qj94sv As if it matters that the loop needs to be taken at least once, however. `if n > 0` doesn't cause the same changes. Am currently doubting about removing this answer

Answer (score 2):

Good question!

Firstly, instead of calling the virtual method directly, you could use the polymorphism to return a function, in the form of a functor, std::function or even a lambda, e.g.

```
struct A{
   virtual std::function<...signature...> getProcessMethod() = 0;
   virtual ~A() = default;
};
```

See the following resources:
[Why use functors over functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451866/why-use-functors-over-functions)

https://www.go4expert.com/articles/cpp-closures-functors-lamdas-stdfunction-t34654/

---

Once you have your function, you can then apply *functional* techniques to whatever the range/iterator/vector you're looping round.  So you could use a `std::transform` to perform a map-reduce on the entire set using the function.  This can be optimised to use a thread pool etc.
[How to replicate map, filter and reduce behaviors in C++ using STL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40901615/how-to-replicate-map-filter-and-reduce-behaviors-in-c-using-stl)

---

For further information I wholeheartedly recommend Ivan Cukic's book on Functional Programming with C++
https://www.amazon.co.uk/Functional-Programming-C-Ivan-Cukic/dp/1617293814

Comment: As the function is `virtual`, return type should have some type-erasure (as `std::function`), resulting to code similar to virtual call.

Comment: std::function is going to have a ton of overhead compared to a virtual function call, [try it](https://ideone.com/cP2UG0)

Comment: @BeyelerStudios: [quick-bench](https://quick-bench.com/q/XFD53CvcCP7BtjQ3sBtKNAWIo2M) shows similar result. (but I think regular virtual call should be easier to devirtualize when possible).

Comment: @Jarod42 yes clang seems to be similar, even with JVApen's mentioned -fstrict-vtable-pointers flag: https://godbolt.org/z/YKfx9d though gcc and icc run waaay faster on virtual calls.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios yes I have a suspicion that `std::function` has a lot of overhead - hence why I suggested it as one option of several.  It would be interesting to see a proper comparison between that and functor, lambda and function pointer.